# Why doesn't the error list clear in Visual Studio 2019 (latest) for the Mac OS Community with Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a feeling this is a problem I have had for ever but would like to get some advice from here.

I had errors in my code so I **commented out** the problem and ran the code again. The code now compiles and works. But when I go back to the errors screen I still see this pointing to the errors for things before I commented out those sections:

[image]

Can someone tell me why this is. Also how can I remove these old errors from the view. Note this is VS for the Mac OS.

For reference.  Here's the comments out code so you can see that there should be no more errors related to it:

<t:PopupEntryFrame>
<r:CustomEntry x:Name="newDeckNameEntry" TextChanged="newDeckNameEntry_TextChanged" />
</t:PopupEntryFrame>
-->
<t:Spacer20 />
<t:PopupEntryHeaderLabel Text="New Deck Description" />
<t:PopupEntryFrame >
<r:CustomEntry x:Name="newDeckDescriptionEntry" TextChanged="newDeckDescriptionEntry_TextChanged" />
</t:PopupEntryFrame>
-->
<t:Spacer30 />

Comment: You could close the IDE and delete the folder bin and obj in your project . Then re-open the project rebuild it .

Comment: Do you agree that it's a VS problem also?  I mean closing the IDE, deleting bin and obj seems extreme way to remove the errors listing when there are no errors?  As far as I recall this is something I've been seeing for the last few years.

Comment: You could post this issue to VS official support forum : **Help -> Report a problem**  . We will follow up it .

Comment: Yeah I see that problem too!